# React Native Calendar list without 3rd party libraries lags

Tags: react-native

This is the code that I write for Calendar List without third-party libraries. The Calendar works fine, the problem is that it lags/delays when selecting the date, also when I open the page on which the calendar is located, the page lags in loading. How can increase the performance of Calendar?

ps. I know there are many third-party libraries, but I don't want to use them.

EXPO SNACK:
https://snack.expo.dev/@stefanosalexandrou/vengeful-green-bananas

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import {
  ScrollView,
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Dimensions,
  Pressable
} from 'react-native';

const Calendar = () => {
  const getCurrentYear = () => {
    const now = new Date();
    return now.getFullYear();
  };

  const isLeapYear = (year) => {
    return (year % 4 === 0 && year % 100 !== 0) || year % 400 === 0;
  };

  const calculateFebruaryDays = (year) => {
    return isLeapYear(year) ? 29 : 28;
  };

  const GetCurrent = (YEAR, ID) => {
    const currentDate = new Date(YEAR, ID, 1);
    const numericDay = (currentDate.getDay() + 6) % 7;
    return numericDay;
  };

  const currentDate = new Date();
  const currentMonth = currentDate.getMonth();
  const currentYear = getCurrentYear();

  // State to store selected dates
  const [selectedDates, setSelectedDates] = useState([]);

  const data = Array.from({ length: 12 }, (_, index) => {
    const monthIndex = (currentMonth + index) % 12;
    const year = currentYear + Math.floor((currentMonth + index) / 12);

    return {
      TITLE: new Date(year, monthIndex, 1).toLocaleString('default', {
        month: 'long',
      }),
      DAY: new Date(year, monthIndex + 1, 0).getDate(),
      YEAR: year,
      EMPTY_DAY: GetCurrent(year, monthIndex),
    };
  });

  const windowWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
  const cont = (windowWidth - 40) / 7;

  // Use useCallback to memoize the selection handler
  const toggleDateSelection = useCallback((date) => {
    setSelectedDates((prevSelectedDates) => {
      if (prevSelectedDates.includes(date)) {
        // If already selected, remove it
        return prevSelectedDates.filter((d) => d !== date);
      } else {
        // If not selected, add it
        return [...prevSelectedDates, date];
      }
    });
  }, []);

  // Function to format the selected dates
  const formatDate = (year, month, day) => {
    const formattedMonth = String(month + 1).padStart(2, '0');
    const formattedDay = String(day).padStart(2, '0');
    return `${year}-${formattedMonth}-${formattedDay}`;
  };

  // Function to format selected dates as YYYY-MM-DD in ascending order
  const formatSelectedDates = () => {
    // Sort the selected dates in ascending order
    const sortedDates = selectedDates.sort((a, b) => {
      const [monthA, dayA, yearA] = a.split(' ');
      const [monthB, dayB, yearB] = b.split(' ');

      // Convert date strings to Date objects for comparison
      const dateA = new Date(yearA, monthToIndex(monthA), parseInt(dayA, 10));
      const dateB = new Date(yearB, monthToIndex(monthB), parseInt(dayB, 10));

      return dateA - dateB;
    });

    // Format the sorted dates
    return sortedDates.map((date) => {
      const [month, day, year] = date.split(' ');
      return formatDate(year, monthToIndex(month), parseInt(day, 10));
    });
  };

  // Map month name to month index
  const monthToIndex = (month) => {
    const months = [
      'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June',
      'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'
    ];
    return months.indexOf(month);
  };

  return (
    <ScrollView style={{ flex: 1, paddingHorizontal: 20 }}>
      {/* Text above the calendar to display selected dates */}
      <Text style={styles.selectedDatesText}>
        Selected Dates: {formatSelectedDates().join(', ')}
      </Text>

      {data.map((item, index) => (
        <View key={index} style={styles.section}>
          <Text style={styles.h1}>
            {item.TITLE} {item.YEAR}
          </Text>
          <View style={styles.grid}>
            {Array.from({ length: item.EMPTY_DAY }, (_, dayIndex) => (
              <View key={dayIndex} style={[styles.empty, { width: cont }]}></View>
            ))}
            {Array.from({ length: item.DAY }, (_, dayIndex) => {
              const day = dayIndex + 1;
              const isCurrentDate =
                day === currentDate.getDate() &&
                item.TITLE ===
                  currentDate.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'long' });

              const isSelected = selectedDates.includes(
                `${item.TITLE} ${day}, ${item.YEAR}`
              );

              return (
                <Pressable
                  key={dayIndex}
                  style={[
                    styles.day,
                    { width: cont },
                    isCurrentDate ? styles.currentDate : null,
                    isSelected ? styles.selectedDate : null, // Highlight selected dates
                  ]}
                  onPress={() => toggleDateSelection(`${item.TITLE} ${day}, ${item.YEAR}`)}
                >
                  <Text
                    style={[
                      styles.h2,
                      isCurrentDate ? styles.currentDateText : null,
                      isSelected ? styles.selectedDateText : null, // Text color for selected dates
                    ]}
                  >
                    {day}
                  </Text>
                </Pressable>
              );
            })}
          </View>
        </View>
      ))}
    </ScrollView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  section: {
    width: '100%',
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  h1: {
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: '600',
    marginBottom: 12,
  },
  h2: {
    fontSize: 14,
    fontWeight: '600',
  },
  grid: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
  day: {
    height: 45,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  empty: {
    height: 45,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  currentDate: {
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
  },
  currentDateText: {
    color: 'white',
  },
  selectedDate: {
    backgroundColor: 'green', // Customize the background color for selected dates
  },
  selectedDateText: {
    color: 'white', // Customize the text color for selected dates
  },
  selectedDatesText: {
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: '600',
    marginBottom: 12,
  },
});

export default Calendar;
```